# Отправка сообщение чат-ботом телеграмм в приватную группу в определенное время

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sendmessage

Ребята всем привет.
Небольшая предыстория.
Есть чат с друзьями где мы общаемся, у есть друг который всегда обещает нам замутить девчёнок, но никогда не мутит.
Каждый раз говорит что в субботу, но прокатывает нас.
Вот созрела идея, сделать бота, что бы слал ему непристойные сообщение каждый день в определенное время.
Собственно всё ради веселья :)
Сделал, а точнее подглядел следующий способ:

```
import telegram
import schedule
import time

# Указываем id бота и токен
bot = telegram.Bot(token='api токен от BotFather')
chat_id = 'id приватного чата'

# Функция, которая будет отправлять сообщение

def send_message():
  message = 'Сообщение, которое нужно отправить'
  bot.send_message (chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

# Задаем время отправки сообщения
schedule.every().day.at("15:00:00").do(send_message)

# Бесконечный цикл для проверки расписания
while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```

Но пишет следующую ошибку

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited
  bot.send_message (chat_id=chat_id, text=message)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что метод bot.send_message возвращает корутину, тут надо использовать await.
Измененный код такой

```
import telegram
import schedule
import time
import asyncio

# Указываем id бота и токен
bot = telegram.Bot(token='api токен от BotFather')
chat_id = 'id приватного чата'

# Функция, которая будет отправлять сообщение
async def send_message():
  message = 'Сообщение, которое нужно отправить'
  await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

# Задаем время отправки сообщения
schedule.every().day.at("15:00:00").do(asyncio.run, send_message())

# Бесконечный цикл для проверки расписания
while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```